# can't validate xml schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, servicestack

We use ServiceStack.NET to build web service and XSD is generated automatically from ServiceStack.NET. The XSD contains two imports:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" />
```

I use many different xml validators to validate this xml schema and all got errors or warnings  that compain about those name namespaces because they can't be found online anywhere. Does anyone have similar experience and can provide some help?

Comment: <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" />

Comment: http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj661424(v=office.12).aspx